# Soft Delete e relacionamentos no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de usar soft delete mas verificar se há relacionamentos/dados/registros ligados ao registro que será excluído antes de excluir.

Isso é claro, utilizando apenas o próprio Laravel.

Sendo assim, como checar os relacionamentos **de maneira automática** antes de executar o soft delete?

Comment: Os relacionamentos no model ou em nível do db? Confesso que fiquei curioso sobre o comportamento do laravel nesses casos

Comment: No model.... como eu faço o Laravel identificar os relacionamentos e não permitir a exclusão, mesmo que seja o soft delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já precisei disto em um projeto e o que fiz foi realizar uma pesquisa antes de realizar o soft-delete. No meu caso foi tranquilo pois apenas 2 tabelas tinham relação com aquela que estava sendo manipulada.

Para trabalhar com um contexto onde você pode ter n-tabelas relacionadas, e algumas vezes tabelas de plugins ou módulos que podem ou não estar ativos, você pode criar uma classe derivada da idéia do padrão observable.

Crie esta classe com um array de modelos que devem ser consultados quando o soft-delete for ser executado. Cada modelo deve se inserir nesta classe quando instanciado/lido.

Uma forma de que o modelo se insira, em Laravel, é criar um register e no momento de registro realizar a inserção.

Desculpe não passar código de exemplo pois não terei como o fazer no momento, espero que a idéia ajude, pois Laravel não tem isso como padrão.

Comment: Por enquanto está sendo minha única solução também. Creio que vai ser o jeito. De qualquer forma agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Tu podes utilizar *[Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events)* assim tu pode chamar um método e fazer as verificações que tu queres, mas não sei se o próprio laravel não faz isso.

```
User::deleting(function($user)
{
    if ( ! $user->isDeleted()) return false; // se tu retorna falso ele não deleta
});
```

Outra opção é usar isso

```
// Laravel's equivalent to calling the constructor on a model
    public static function boot()
    {
        // make the parent (Eloquent) boot method run
        parent::boot();    

        // cause a soft delete of a product to cascade to children so they are also soft  deleted
        static::deleted(function($product)
        {
            $product->images()->delete();
            $product->descriptions()->delete();
            foreach($product->variants as $variant)
            {
                $variant->options()->delete();
                $variant->delete();
            }
        });
    }
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243637/laravel-4-cascading-soft-deletes